scrape link for jwplayer calculated with JS using python
I'm trying to scrape video link (m3u8) from this website:
https://deaddrive.xyz/embed/fa31e
While inspecting the page, I realized that the link is calculated on the fly using JS in the function:


<script type="text/javascript">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+c.toString(a)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('q 4g=[];16("ai").ah({ag:[{2i:"1h://af.ae.1w/ad/ac/ab/aa/a9.a8?t=a7&s=3z&e=a6&f=40&a5=2k&i=0.4&a4=a3&a2=2k&a1=2k&a0=4m"}],9z:"1h://4k.4j/9y.4i?v=4m",9x:"2j%",9w:"2j%",9v:"9u",9t:"9s.85",9r:\'9q\',9p:\'9o\',9n:{9m:{4l:"#1k",9l:"#1k"},9k:{9j:"#1k"},9i:{4l:"#1k"}},9h:"1n",p:[{2i:"/45?42=9g&1e=29&9f=1h://4k.4j/9e.4i",9d:"9c"}],22:{9b:1,9a:\'#1k\',99:\'#98\',97:"94",93:30,92:2j,},"91":{"90":"4e","8z":"8y"},\'8x\':{"8w":"8v"},8u:"8t",8s:"1h://2h.1w",4h:{2i:"1h://2h.1w/8r-2d/8q.8p","1v":u,2f:"1h://2h.1w/?8o=4h",1c:"8n-8m",8l:"5",1v:u},8k:1n,20:[0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,2]});q 2e,2g;q 8j=0,8i=0,8h=0;q n=16();q 4b=0,8g=0,8f=0,1b=0;$.8e({8d:{\'8c-8b\':\'8a-89\'}});n.18(\'4f\',o(x){k(5>0&&x.1c>=5&&2g!=1){2g=1;$(\'1j.88\').86(\'84\')}4g.83(1d=>{k(1d.4f<=x.1c&&1d.4c==0){k(1d.82==\'4e\'){n.81(1d.2f)}2q{q a=4d.80(\'7z\');a.7y=1d.2f;4d.7x.7w(a);}1d.4c=1}});k(x.1c>=1b+5||x.1c<1b){1b=x.1c;2b.7u(\'2a\',7t.7s(1b),{7r:60*60*24*7})}});n.18(\'1p\',o(x){4b=x.1c});n.18(\'7q\',o(x){4a(x)});n.18(\'7p\',o(){$(\'1j.49\').7o();2b.7n(\'2a\')});n.18(\'7m\',o(x){});o 4a(x){$(\'1j.49\').1v();$(\'#7k\').1v();k(2e)1y;2e=1;1u=0;k(7j.7i===7h){1u=1}$.3y(\'/45?42=7g&7f=7e&7d=40-87-3t-3z-7c&7b=1&7a=79.78&1u=\'+1u,o(2d){$(\'#77\').76(2d)});q 1b=2b.3y(\'2a\');k(1b>0){16().1p(1b)}}o 74(){q p=n.1z(3x);3w.3v(p);k(p.1e>1){2o(i=0;i<p.1e;i++){k(p[i].2n==3x){3w.3v(\'!!=\'+i);n.2l(i)}}}}n.18(\'72\',o(){16().23(\'<w 3g="3f://3e.3d.3c/3b/w" 3a="b-w-1g b-w-1g-71" 39="0 0 1s 1s" 38="u"><1q d="m 25.70,57.6z v 6y.3 c 0.6x,2.6w 2.6u,4.6t 4.8,4.8 h 62.7 v -19.3 h -48.2 v -96.4 3u 6s.6r v 19.3 c 0,5.3 3.6,7.2 8,4.3 l 41.8,-27.9 c 2.6q,-1.6p 4.6o,-5.6n 2.7,-8 -0.6m,-1.6l -1.6k,-2.6j -2.7,-2.7 l -41.8,-27.9 c -4.4,-2.9 -8,-1 -8,4.3 v 19.3 3u 30.6i c -2.6h,0.6g -4.6f,2.6e -4.9,4.9 z m 3t.6d,73.6c c -3.3s,-6.3r -10.3q,-10.3p -17.7,-10.6 -7.3o,0.3n -13.3m,4.3k -17.7,10.6 -8.1t,14.3j -8.1t,32.3i 0,46.3 3.3s,6.3r 10.3q,10.3p 17.7,10.6 7.3o,-0.3n 13.3m,-4.3k 17.7,-10.6 8.1t,-14.3j 8.1t,-32.3i 0,-46.3 z m -17.7,47.2 c -7.8,0 -14.4,-11 -14.4,-24.1 0,-13.1 6.6,-24.1 14.4,-24.1 7.8,0 14.4,11 14.4,24.1 0,13.1 -6.5,24.1 -14.4,24.1 z m -47.6b,9.6a v -51 l -4.8,4.8 -6.8,-6.8 13,-12.69 c 3.68,-3.67 8.66,-0.65 8.2,3.4 v 62.64 z"></1q></w>\',"63 10 33",o(){16().1p(16().31()+10)},"3h");$("1j[26=3h]").2y().2x(\'.b-1g-28\');16().23(\'<w 3g="3f://3e.3d.3c/3b/w" 3a="b-w-1g b-w-1g-28" 39="0 0 1s 1s" 38="u"><1q d="61.2,5z.5y.1a,21.1a,0,0,0-17.7-10.6,21.1a,21.1a,0,0,0-17.7,10.6,44.1r,44.1r,0,0,0,0,46.3,21.1a,21.1a,0,0,0,17.7,10.6,21.1a,21.1a,0,0,0,17.7-10.6,44.1r,44.1r,0,0,0,0-46.5x-17.7,47.2c-7.8,0-14.4-11-14.4-24.5w.6-24.1,14.4-24.1,14.4,11,14.4,24.5v.4,37.5u,95.5,37.5t-43.4,9.7v-5s-4.8,4.8-6.8-6.8,13-5r.8,4.8,0,0,1,8.2,3.5q.7l-9.6-.5p-5o.5n.5m.36,4.36,0,0,1-4.8,4.5l.6v-19.5k.2v-96.5j.5i.5h,5.3-3.6,7.2-8,4.3l-41.8-27.5g.35,6.35,0,0,1-2.7-8,5.34,5.34,0,0,1,2.7-2.5f.8-27.5e.4-2.9,8-1,8,4.5d.5c.5b.29,4.29,0,0,1,5a.1,57.59"></1q></w>\',"58 10 33",o(){q 1o=16().31()-10;k(1o<0)1o=0;16().1p(1o)},"2z");$("1j[26=2z]").2y().2x(\'.b-1g-28\');});n.18("r",o(56){q p=n.1z();k(p.1e<2)1y;$(\'.b-j-g-26\').18(\'55\',()=>{$(\'.b-g-r\').15(\'y-1m\',\'u\');$(\'.b-g-r\').15(\'y-1i\',\'u\');$(\'#b-j-g-r\').1l(\'b-j-g-1f\')});$(\'.b-j-54-53\').52(o(){$(\'#b-j-g-r\').1l(\'b-j-g-1f\');$(\'.b-g-r\').15(\'y-1i\',\'u\')});n.23("/50/4z.w","4y 4x",o(){$(\'.b-2t\').4w(\'b-j-2s\');$(\'.b-j-22, .b-2w-2u, .b-j-20\').15(\'y-1m\',\'u\');$(\'.b-j-22, .b-2w-2u, .b-j-20\').15(\'y-1i\',\'u\');k($(\'.b-2t\').4v(\'b-j-2s\')){$(\'.b-g-r\').15(\'y-1m\',\'1n\');$(\'.b-g-r\').15(\'y-1i\',\'1n\');$(\'.b-j-g\').1l(\'b-j-g-1f\');$(\'#b-j-g-r\').2r(\'b-j-g-1f\');$(\'.b-j-g:4u\').2r(\'b-j-g-1f\');}2q{$(\'.b-g-r\').15(\'y-1m\',\'u\');$(\'.b-g-r\').15(\'y-1i\',\'u\');$(\'.b-j-g-r\').1l(\'b-j-g-1f\')}},"4t");k(!4s.4r(\'4q\'))4p("2p(\'4o\')",4n)});q 1x;o 2p(2m){q p=n.1z();k(p.1e>1){2o(i=0;i<p.1e;i++){k(p[i].2n==2m){k(i==1x){1y}1x=i;n.2l(i)}}}}',36,379,'|||||||||||jw|||||submenu|||settings|if|||player|function|tracks|var|audioTracks|||false||svg||aria|||||||attr|jwplayer||on||589|lastt|position|item|length|active|icon|https|expanded|div|FFFFFF|removeClass|checked|true|tt|seek|path|769|240|60009|adb|hide|com|current_audio|return|getAudioTracks|playbackRates||captions|addButton|||button||rewind|974|tto5kba0nbcmc1|ls||data|vvplay|link|vvad|vidhide|file|100|91ejjoFPHQ2N|setCurrentAudioTrack|audio_name|name|for|audio_set|else|addClass|open|controls|quality||tooltip|insertAfter|detach|ff00||getPosition||sec|887|013|867|178|focusable|viewBox|class|2000|org|w3|www|http|xmlns|ff11|06475|23525|29374||97928|30317|31579|29683|38421|30626|72072|163|H|log|console|track_name|get|1724940213|9118284||op|||dl||||video_ad|doPlay|prevt|loaded|document|vast|time|uas|logo|jpg|cc|laving|text|3320|300|हिन्दी|setTimeout|default_audio|getItem|localStorage|dualSound|last|hasClass|toggleClass|Track|Audio|dualy|images||mousedown|buttons|topbar|click|event||Rewind|778Z|214|2A4|3H209|3v19|9c4|7l41|9a6|3c0|1v19|4H79|3h48|8H146|3a4|2v125|130|1Zm162|4v62|13a4|51l|278Zm|278|1S103|1s6|3Zm|078a21|131||M113||Forward|69999|88605|21053|03598|02543|99999|72863|77056|04577|422413|210431|860275|03972|689569|893957|124979|52502|174985|57502|04363|13843|480087|93574|99396|160|76396|164107||63589|03604|125|778|993957|rewind2|ready||set_audio_track||html|fviews|xyz|deaddrive|referer|embed|7a70a6d4c15fada1bbee046caaeeb156|hash|o5kba0nbcmc1|file_code|view|undefined|cRAds1|window|over_player_msg||pause|remove|show|complete|play|ttl|round|Math|set||appendChild|body|src|script|createElement|playAd|xtype|forEach|slow||fadeIn||video_ad_fadein|cache|no|Cache|Content|headers|ajaxSetup|v2done|tott|pop3done|vastdone2|vastdone1|playbackRateControls|margin|left|top|ref|png|logo_28779|upload|aboutlink|VidHide|abouttext|720p|866|qualityLabels|insecure|vpaidmode|client|advertising|fontOpacity|backgroundOpacity|Tahoma|||fontFamily|303030|backgroundColor|color|userFontScale|thumbnails|kind|o5kba0nbcmc10000|url|get_slides|androidhls|menus|progress|timeslider|icons|controlbar|skin|none|fullscreenOrientationLock|auto|preload|973|duration|uniform|stretching|height|width|o5kba0nbcmc1_xt|image|asn|p2|p1|500|sp|srv|129600|zwM4N63Iatoh52phXBqaJRlmUGtZ15AENgnDrxl3BwA|m3u8|master|o5kba0nbcmc1_n|01823|01|hls2|hgagecdn|V0eSu3D58smE|sources|setup|vplayer'.split('|')))
</script>



Can I somehow execute this JS script within python using Selenium or something else and unscramble the m3u8 link?
Thank you

It would be better to inspect the network requests and catch the one with the m3u8 URL.

Can you point to some code snippet/guide on how to do this)
